# Facebook graph api user search by country

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know a way to search users by country in facebook graph api?

Using following request:
search?q=jake&type=user&location=usa

But it just gives all the jakes available even if I change the location to any other country.

Is there a way to find all the users for a given country? Can I somehow use wildcards in q or All statement? Tried but no success I get data[]

Comment: No, there is no way to do that via Graph API.

Comment: @CBroe is there any other approach you would recommend to solve the problem?

Comment: Without a proper explanation of what you would need this data for, and in what context it is supposed to be used, I don’t even see a problem to solve yet.

Comment: @CBroe I want to collect stats on fb users for a country